# Multi-conditional search on DataFrame rows return empty results

Tags: python, dataframe

I try to return a specific row conditionally, firstly I tries this:

```
print(london_df[(london_df['spend'] == london_df.spend.max()) & (london_df['year'] == 2017)][['quarter']])
```

And it returns the right result:

```
        quarter
53698      Q3
```

But when I try to look at the result of year 2018, it won't work:

```
print(london_df[(london_df['spend'] == london_df.spend.max()) & (london_df['year'] == 2018)][['quarter']])
```

Result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [quarter]
Index: []
```

What is going on to my dataframe?

And actually I tried other years too, but only year 2017 would work.

Comment: please share a snippet of your data

Comment: Because there's no match for the other years? The `df.spend.max()` probably is only occurring in `2017`.  Mind you the `max` is of the *entire* dataframe, not *per year*.  Otherwise, you may be thinking of a groupby.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually wanted the `max` column `'spend'` of each year:

```
df.groupby('year')['spend'].max().reset_index().merge(df[['year', 'spend', 'quarter']], how='left')
```

For example, given the below `df`:

```
   year  spend quarter
0   2016    100      Q1
1   2016    200      Q2
2   2016    300      Q3
3   2016    400      Q4
4   2017    100      Q1
5   2017    400      Q2
6   2017    300      Q3
7   2017    200      Q4
8   2018    400      Q1
9   2018    300      Q2
10  2018    200      Q3
11  2018    100      Q4
12  2019    300      Q1
13  2019    200      Q2
14  2019    100      Q3
15  2019    400      Q4
```

Result would be:

> ```
>    year  spend quarter
> 0  2016    400      Q4
> 1  2017    400      Q2
> 2  2018    400      Q1
> 3  2019    400      Q4
> ```